# Running jquery function when OnChange is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, firebug

Need to run the toggleSlide() jquery function when the user selects a value in the dropdown menu.

In Firebug i get the error "selectMenu is not a function" but i am not sure how to correct this as I am very new to javascript.

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
        slideToggle();
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is slideToggle():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {
   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
});

</script>
```

Yes jquery is loaded correctly because I have other jquery elements working. Also, I do have the select menu's id set to "selectMenu"

Ian, unfortunately that does not work.

Meder, could you explain a little more please?

Comment: Please post the code to slideToggle() as well.

Comment: two things - 1) have you loaded jQuery correctly, 2) do you have an item with ID 'selectMenu' on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put your jquery code inside the document ready wrapper:

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
        slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. It would make sense if you had a function named `selectMenu`. Anyways, make sure you do it on DOM ready `$(function(){ /* paste your code here */ });` and make sure you arent making typos.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you have a  element with the id `selectMenu`? This should work:

```
<select id="selectMenu">
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
        slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```